# We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here: remote:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
 npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
 npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.37
 npm ERR! Found: react@16.13.0
 npm ERR! node_modules/react
 npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
 npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
 npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.12.0 || ^5.0.0-beta.0" from @material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.37
 npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/data-grid
 npm ERR!       @material-ui/data-grid@"^4.0.0-alpha.37" from the root project
 npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
 npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/icons
 npm ERR!       @material-ui/icons@"^4.5.1" from material-ui-treeview@5.0.0
 npm ERR!       node_modules/material-ui-treeview
 npm ERR!         material-ui-treeview@"^5.0.0" from the root project
 npm ERR!       2 more (react-material-ui-carousel, the root project)
 npm ERR!     4 more (@material-ui/lab, material-ui-treeview, ...)
 npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/system@4.12.2
 npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core/node_modules/@material-ui/system
 npm ERR!     @material-ui/system@"^4.12.2" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
 npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/core
 npm ERR!       peer @material-ui/core@"^4.12.0 || ^5.0.0-beta.0" from @material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.37
 npm ERR!       node_modules/@material-ui/data-grid
 npm ERR!         @material-ui/data-grid@"^4.0.0-alpha.37" from the root project
 npm ERR!       5 more (@material-ui/icons, @material-ui/lab, ...)
 npm ERR!   25 more (@material-ui/utils, @material-ui/icons, ...)
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
 npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.37
 npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/data-grid
 npm ERR!   @material-ui/data-grid@"^4.0.0-alpha.37" from the root project
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
 npm ERR! node_modules/react
 npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0" from @material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.37
 npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/data-grid
 npm ERR!     @material-ui/data-grid@"^4.0.0-alpha.37" from the root project
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
 npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
 npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

The material-Ui dependency you installed is not compatible with your version of react. To be on a safer side, remove that dependency from your node modules

Comment: removed the node module folder but still getting the same error
 While resolving: @mui/material@5.10.6
 Found: react@16.13.0
    react@"^16.13.0" from the root project
   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.10.4
   node_modules/@emotion/react
     @emotion/react@"^11.10.4" from the root project
     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.10.4
     node_modules/@emotion/styled
       @emotion/styled@"^11.10.4" from the root project
       3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
     3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)

Comment: Can someone help on this, still waiting for the resolution